# Rails: Form_for: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am completely new to RoR and was trying to build a simple blog, but already got stuck at the "Adding Post" function.

The following Error Message pops up when I load `.../posts/new`:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is what my posts controller looks like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index 
end

def new 
end

def create 
    render plain: params[:post].inspect
end
```

end

Here is what my `new.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I had set posts as resource in my routes. The surprising thing is, that on my friend's laptop, the code works.

I would be very happy about any advice, and apologize for the silly question.

Comment: I edited your title, and removed profanity from it. Please don't use swear words, if they are not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes with:

```
$rake routes
```

And you'll see that the posts_path with an id its used to update a "post" and not to create one, you'll also found the path you want to create a new "post".

You might say: but i don't have an update action. If on your routes file you used the resources keyword you do, even if the action itself is missing.

Update:
Remove the

```
url: post_path
```

From your form_for call

My recommendation, check out the [rails guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `form_for` helper is looking for a resource object to operate with, and you're giving it a symbol. I suspect it's assuming that's an action URL instead, and translating (or trying to) that symbol into a route.

Using `form_for` in a `new` action, the pattern is usually to create a new resource and feed that into the `form_for` helper:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

```
<%= form_for @post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: The @post object won't have an id, so the form will still complain, the problem is the path he's using is not for creating but updating an object.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Forms don't care about resource IDs unless you make them, and even then they will happily accept a nil.

Comment: but it is not the form_for thats complaining its the post_path and they do care about nil

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Yes, but the point is the `post_path` helper shouldn't be getting called at all - it needs an *object*, not a route.

Comment: Thats the solution, removing the url: post_path part and it will pick the correct path automatically.